# Yii2 Grid view pjax search on keypress

Tags: search, gridview, yii2, keypress, pjax

I am trying to update yii2 grid view using pjax on keypress, Like by default in Yii2 grid view searching works on blur or on change event.

What I am looking for to overwrite this functionality on keypress.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should do following:

1. Disable default submit events and bind keyup event on filter inputs.
2. Focus active input after updating

Here is a simple working example:

```
var input;
var submit_form = false;
var filter_selector = '#grid-id-filters input';

$("body").on('beforeFilter', "#grid-id" , function(event) {
    return submit_form;
});

$("body").on('afterFilter', "#grid-id" , function(event) {
    submit_form = false;
});

$(document)
.off('keydown.yiiGridView change.yiiGridView', filter_selector)
.on('keyup', filter_selector, function() {
    input = $(this).attr('name');

    if(submit_form === false) {
        submit_form = true;
        $("#grid-id").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
    }
})
.on('pjax:success', function() {
    var i = $("[name='"+input+"']");
    var val = i.val();
    i.focus().val(val);
});
```

View:

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-id']) ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'id'               => 'grid-id',
    'dataProvider'     => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'      => $filterModel,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        'title'
    ]
]);?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Its working fine for very first time, but after first call no ajax triggered.

Comment: Do you use this construction $(document).on('keyup', ...), or this $(filter_selector).click(func(){}) ?

Comment: I have used as you have mentioned in answer. 
and due to 
.on('keyup', filter_selector, function() {   there will no issue of binding too..

Comment: there was issue that after first ajax call its not callback success "pjax:success" event so submit_form value remain true.. 

any idea why :success event not trigger

Comment: I've checked again my code in the answer in a live project, and it works. 
Did you wrap js code in $(document).ready(function () {}); ?
Probably you have an errors in your controller or model. Try to bind pjax:error callback and enable errors displaying.

Comment: Eugene@ I found your answer very useful and using that I have created a jQuery plugin to fix issue. https://github.com/sachingvit/Yii2-customization/blob/master/Yii2-grid-view/Yii2-gridview-pjax.js